# CnPack distorsiona la pantalla al cargar o compilar en Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Desde hace un tiempo estoy presentando que mi pantalla/video se distorsiona al cargar un formulario, ubicar el puntero sobre una variable en el código y/o compilar un problema, he buscado una solución al caso y no he podido dar con el problema, he actualizado los drivers de video del equipo, cambiado RAM y nada, al desinstalar Cnpack todo funciona bien. Actualicé a la última versión de cnpack y el problema persiste ¿Alguno de ustedes ha tenido problema similar?, me gustaría cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Uso Delphi 7, CnWizards_1.2.6.1126, Windows 10.

[image: DISTORSION_PANTALLA_COMPILA_DELPHI7]

Gracias anticipadas.

¿Como puedo resolver el problema?

Comment: Hola. No tengo mayor conocimiento en Delphi, pero bien podría ser algún conflicto de librerías entre lo que trae CnPack y lo que tienes instalado?

Comment: veo que cnPack tiene foros dónde es probable que encuentres ayuda, sobre todo tomando en cuenta que Delphi 7 tiene más de 20 años de antigüedad.